# Update/Edit many-to-many tables using asp core mvc and sql Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I have asp core mvc project , That tracks orders , The user will create a new tracking and add many orders in it ,and the order may will added in many tracking, so the relationship between the orders and tracking is many-to-many , and each order has a driver , so the relationship between orders and driver is one-to-many , so I created models as below .

1- Orders Model :

```
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int? OrderNo { get; set; }
    [Column("DriverID")]
    public int? DriverId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DriverId))]
    [InverseProperty("Orders")]
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TrackingOrder.Order))]
    public virtual ICollection<TrackingOrder> TrackingOrders { get; set; }
```

2- Driver Model :

```
    [Key]
    [Column("DriverID")]
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DriverName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Order.Driver))]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

3- Tracking Model :

```
    [Key]
    [Column("TrackingID")]
    public int TrackingId { get; set; }
    [Column("TDate", TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? Tdate { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int DiverID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(TrackingOrder.Tracking))]
    public virtual ICollection<TrackingOrder> TrackingOrders { get; set; }
    public object OrderNo { get; internal set; }
    public object DriverID { get; internal set; }
```

4- Tracking_Orders Model :

```
    [Key]
    [Column("TrackingID")]
    public int TrackingId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("OrderID")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OrderId))]
    [InverseProperty("TrackingOrders")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TrackingId))]
    [InverseProperty("TrackingOrders")]
    public virtual Tracking Tracking { get; set; }
```

Then I added a View Model (AddNewTracking) to create a new tracking  :

```
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int? TrackingID { get; set; }
    public int? OrderNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Tdate { get; set; }
   
    [Column("DriverID")]
    public int? DriverId { get; set; }

   public Driver driver { get; set; }
```

Then I added controller to create new tracking using Stored Procedure and it is working correctly as below :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind("OrderNo,Tdate,DriverId")] AddNewTracking addNewTracking)
    {
        var orderNo = addNewTracking.OrderNo;
        var ch = (from x in _context.Orders
                  where x.OrderNo == orderNo
                  select x).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           if(ch.Count>0)
            {
                ViewBag.Duplicate = "Order No Already Exist";
            }
           else
            {
                
                
                int NewTrack = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"NewTracking @OrderNo={addNewTracking.OrderNo},@DriverID={addNewTracking.DriverId},@TrackingDate={addNewTracking.Tdate}");
                ViewBag.successMsg = "Order Added";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
            ViewData["DriverId"] = new SelectList(_context.Drivers, "DriverId", "DriverName");

            
            return View();
```

Here is my insert stored procedure Code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewTracking]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@OrderNo int,
@DriverID int,
@TrackingDate date

AS
BEGIN
Declare @OrderID int
Declare @TrackingID int
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select @OrderID=OrderID from Orders where OrderNo=@OrderNo
select @TrackingID=TrackingID from Tracking where TDate=@TrackingDate
if (@OrderID is null)
begin
insert into Orders values (@OrderNo,@DriverID)
select @OrderID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
End

if (@TrackingID is null)
begin
insert into Tracking values (@TrackingDate)
select @TrackingID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end
insert into Tracking_Order values (@TrackingID,@OrderID)
END
```

Now, I want to write a stored procedure to edit the new tracking (edit orderNo or driver name )

I created View model for editing named (update) with code below :

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime Tdate { get; set; }

    [Column("DriverID")]
    public int? DriverId { get; set; }

    public Driver driver { get; set; }
```

So , how I'll write Sql stored procedure to Edit as per (update) view model and put it in the code below :

```
    // POST:/Edit/5
    NewTracking
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

    }
```

I hope that I describe my issue correctly .

Thanks .

Comment: I think you can use `ExecuteSqlRaw` to do that

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I'll do , but I want to know what sql raw should I write to execute the editing. I don't have any idea what I'll write inside sql raw .